# Would it be stupid to recode `dim` to return `length` if `dim(x)==NULL`?

Tags: r, primitive

As pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18487213/563329) and copious official & unofficial R documentation,

```
x <- complex(15)
dim(x) == NULL
```

For me it's annoying to have to write a separate method (or `if` clause) for atomic vectors rather than being able to use `dim(x)[1]`. Would it be stupid to recode `dim` (a primitive) so it automatically returns `length` if `dim(x)==NULL`?

To be a bit more concrete: Are popular packages going to break if I recode `dim` in let's say my `.Rprofile`? Is this stupid for another reason I'm not seeing?

Comment: Do you see any downside to just calling the more general function something like `Dim`, as in `Dim <- function(x) {if(is.vector(x)) length(x) else dim(x)}`?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien That's a good idea.

Comment: See `NROW` and `NCOL` for functions to return extents in a dimension-agnostic way.

Comment: @HongOoi They work of course but still require me to write extra code for something which seemingly shouldn't be so obtuse.

Comment: @HongOoi For example `x <- complex(15); nrow(x)==NULL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unclear what you're trying to do, but the `NROW` and `NCOL` functions are ways to retrieve extents in a dimension-agnostic way. They treat vectors as column vectors, so `NROW(X)` is the same as `length(x)` and `NCOL(x)` is 1 when `x` is a vector.

```
> x <- numeric(10) # or complex, character, logical, etc
> nrow(x)
NULL
> NROW(x)
[1] 10
> NCOL(x)
[1] 1

> m <- matrix(1:10, nrow=5)
> nrow(m)
[1] 5
> NROW(m)
[1] 5
> NCOL(m)
[1] 2
```

Comment: Thanks @Hong Ooi. I didn't realise in comments that capitalisation mattered.

Comment: This answer is good, but the other question is much better.  That is why I switched the duplicates.

Comment: Or, at least, the other question is more likely to get google hits.